Prevent logging multicast address nftables
I am trying to log any port accesses that aren't allowed using nftables. However, my router spams the multicast address and I want to prevent logging these accesses. Here is one such log entry that I do not want to log:
[33746.85] IN=enp5s0 OUT= MACSRC=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx MACDST=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx MACPROTO=0800 SRC=10.0.0.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=31249 DF OPT (94040000) PROTO=2

This is my current nftables.conf file, I have tried to just drop the access based on the source and destition IP, however the event is still logged:
#!/usr/sbin/nft -f

flush ruleset

table inet filter {
    chain input {
        type filter hook input priority 0;
    
        # block everything by default
        policy drop;
        
        # allow established/related connections
        ct state {established, related} accept

        # early drop of invalid connections
        ct state invalid drop

        # allow from loopback
        iifname lo accept

        # allow icmp
        ip protocol icmp accept

        # allow ssh,http,https
        udp dport {https} accept
        tcp dport {http,https} accept
        tcp dport {ssh} accept

        # ignore broadcast messages from router
        # (this doesn't seem to work)
        ip saddr 10.0.0.1 ip daddr 244.0.0.1 drop

        # log anything else that made it here
        log flags all
    }
    chain forward {
        type filter hook forward priority 0;
        drop
    }
    chain output {
        type filter hook output priority 0;
    }
}

Thank you for the help!
